# Switching views loses Tab Bar

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

I am building basic application. It uses the tab bar with 3 views. I have a button on the first view. When i click it, i want it to switch to like the 3rd view but keep the tab bar at the bottom. Right now, i have it working, but when it switches to the 3rd view, i lose the tab bar.

I am new so take it easy on me. I have tried searching in this site, but nothing helps entirely. If possible please provide the code and which files it should go into.

In my .h i put this code:
`-(IBAction) btnClickedSell1:(id) sender;`

In the .m i put this code:

```
-(IBAction) btnClickedSell1:(id) sender {
    Selling *second = [[Selling alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
}
```

I believe i must have the right code however i'm not sure of which files they should go into exactly and the exact steps to take in IB.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `presentModalViewController:animated`, if you just want to switch to the 3rd view I think you should try this code:

```
 [yourTabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];
```

you can get **yourTabBarController** by NSApplicationDelegate if your app is based on TabBar application.

Comment: Thank you for your help. can you please help rewrite what I need to here? -(IBAction) btnClickedDone:(id) sender {
 FirstViewController *second = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
 [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

> In tab based Application  each bar button is act as like ViewController. So you can redirect into next ViewController You can't keep your first Bar button.